# Custom TCP-Protocol on node.js

Tags: node.js

how i can implement a custom protocol on a Node.js NET-Client?

The problem is:

I want to connect to a server. That server has an simple protocol.
Each packet has a length-prefix, it means the first byte say how long the packet is.

How i can implement that?
How i can read for example the first byte to get the packet-length to read the other stuff?

```
var net         = require('net');
var client      = new net.Socket();

client.connect(2204, 'myexampledomain.com', function() {
    console.log('Connecting...', protocol);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
});

client.on('timeout', function() {
    console.log('timeout');
});

client.on('drain', function() {
    console.log('drain');
});

client.on('error', function() {
    console.log('error');
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connect');
    client.write("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to maintain an internal buffer holding received data and check if it has `length` bytes before slicing the packet from it. The buffer must be concatenated with received data until it has `length` bytes and emptied on receiving a full packet. This can be better handled using a Transform stream.

This is what I used in my json-rpc implementation. Each JSON packet is `lengthPrefixed`. The message doesn't have to be JSON – you can replace the call to `this.push(JSON.parse(json.toString()));`.

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

function JsonTransformer(options) {
    if (!(this instanceof JsonTransformer)) {
        return new JsonTransformer(options);
    }
    Transform.call(this, {
        objectMode: true
    });
/*Transform.call(this);
    this._readableState.objectMode = false;
    this._writableState.objectMode = true;*/
    this.buffer = new Buffer(0);
    this.lengthPrefix = options.lengthPrefix || 2;
    this._readBytes = {
        1: 'readUInt8',
        2: 'readUInt16BE',
        4: 'readUInt32BE'
    }[this.lengthPrefix];
}

JsonTransformer.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: JsonTransformer,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false
    }
});


function transform() {
    var buffer = this.buffer,
        lengthPrefix = this.lengthPrefix;
    if (buffer.length > lengthPrefix) {
        this.bytes = buffer[this._readBytes](0);
        if (buffer.length >= this.bytes + lengthPrefix) {
            var json = buffer.slice(lengthPrefix, this.bytes + lengthPrefix);
            this.buffer = buffer.slice(this.bytes + lengthPrefix);
            try {
                this.push(JSON.parse(json.toString()));
            } catch(err) {
                this.emit('parse error', err);
            }

            transform.call(this);
        }
    }
}

JsonTransformer.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    this.buffer = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, chunk]);
    transform.call(this);
    next();
}

JsonTransformer.prototype._flush = function() {
    console.log('Flushed...');
}

var json = new JsonTransformer({lengthPrefix: 2});
var socket = require('net').createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.pipe(json).on('data', console.log);
});
socket.listen(3000);


module.exports = JsonTransformer;
```

[json-transformer](https://github.com/cPu1/jsonFrame/blob/master/lib/json-frame.js)

Comment: Only client side... but i must work with `pipe()`? Problem is: the `data` event give's me no results, it seems to be not called. But it's 100% safe that when i write "Hello World" that the Server send a answer back to the client.

Comment: A `Transform` stream is endpoint-agnostic, you can use it in your client by piping your client socket to it. Working with `pipe` isn't required, you can use the `transform` function to implement length-prefixed messaging. `var transformer = new JsonTransformer({lengthPrefix: 1}); client.pipe(transformer).on('data', function (data) { console.log('Received packet from server', data); });`